# Using result of UDF in one column into another column that is calling a different UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I'm new to Spark and Python, and I'm trying to get add a new column into an existing dataframe. However, the new column comes from udf of a result of another udf. It works with smaller datasets but when I have millions of records, there seems to be some optimization going on that causes the second column to be evaluated first before the first column is finished. I tried forcing the dataframe to get the results early by doing multiple things including rdd.count() at the end of each withColumn and saveAsTable(). Both of which didn't work. I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'ValueError: time data 'None' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d''
```

Here is a simple example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DateType, IntegerType, StringType, LongType, DecimalType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
```

First udf:

```
def get_new_date(date): # 2019-03-04 
  newDate = date
  
  if date is not None:
    dt = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    newDate = dt + timedelta(days=5)

  return newDate   # 2019-03-09
```

Second udf:

```
def get_lastname_year(fullName, date): # John Doe, "201"
  lastname = ''
  year = ''
  
  # get last name
  if fullName is not None:
    index = fullName.index(" ")
    lastname = fullName[:index]
  
  # get year
  if date is None:
    date = ''
  else:
    date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
  if date != '':
    dt = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    year = dt.year

  return f"{lastname}{year}" # John2019
```

UDFs:

```
udf_get_new_date = udf(get_new_date, DateType())
udf_get_lastname_year = udf(get_lastname_year, StringType())
```

Smaller dataset that worked:

```
data = [("John Doe","2020-08-20"),("Mary Jane",None)]
columns =["full_name","date"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,columns)

df = (df.withColumn("NewDate", udf_get_new_date(F.col("date")))
        .withColumn("LastNameYear", udf_get_lastname_year(F.col("full_name"), F.col("NewDate")))
     )

display(df)
```

[See result of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bRZU.png)

Comment: Why use UDF for something that could be done with Spark SQL functions? That can give a better performance and avoid problems like this with UDFs

Comment: My UDF is a lot more complicated than the example given. The UDF is an existing function being used somewhere else so I didn’t want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The example you provided isn't too helpful because it does not give any errors. Could you try to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I only get this error with large dataset. I’m looking into breaking the dataset now to see if I can pinpoint some specific records. Will get back to you on that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I figured out the problem by narrowing down to which file caused the issue. It turns out not to be a Spark or Databricks issue but a Python thing. One of my UDF evaluates str(x) and if x is None, it will return 'None' instead of None or ''. Therefore, when the next UDF gets called, 'None' made it through the if x != ''.